# amazon alexa skill not properly running working python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Im working on a simple amazon alexa skill in python.
I have wrote all my code for this simple application and loaded it into my lambada function
i have tested that lambada has loaded my imported libraries and that it works with them but when i use this final code it gets a "problem with the requested skills response"

```
    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

        # https://repl.it/repls/UselessOptimalPipeline

        url = "http://jokepro.dx.am/"

        source = requests.get(url)
        bs4call = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")

        obj = bs4call.find('object')

        text = requests.get(url + obj['data']).text
        # print(text) # <-- to print the textfile

        finalJoke = random.choice(text.splitlines())

        speak_output = finalJoke

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                #.ask()
                .response
        )
```

this is the handler function

is lambada conflicting with anything in that code? why is it not working?

update: heres some relevant info

requirements.txt

```
boto3==1.9.216
ask-sdk-core==1.11.0
bs4==4.8.2
requests==2.22.0
```

[image: Not Giving any response which signifies an error...]

This was ALL dont through the amazon dev console https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask

Comment: So now is working?

Comment: @rivamarco no its not working at all

Comment: Can you give us the traceback please?

Comment: never got one just got no response from the skill, ASK doesnt give tracebacks and thats a huge problem

Comment: If it's an Alexa-hosted skill, in the "Code" tab, at the bottom left of page there's a link to the "Logs: Amazon CloudWatch". This might give you a better idea of what the error/exception is. Also mentioned in the [Alexa Skills Kit docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html#logs).

Comment: @OscarSchafer the code doesnt have a problem and i dont see whats what in there

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
My apologies for not requesting full detail of your issue

Based on my expirementation, your issue is related to the dependencies not being configured correctly. When deploying the function, *ALL* dependencies must be listed within the `requriements.txt`. In order to get the proper dependencies I would recommend using `pipenv`.

For Example the following commands will show you the complete dependency tree for your project:

- `pipenv install requests`
- `pipenv install bs4`
- `pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt`

The result of these commands shows your `requirements.txt` file with the following dependencies as a result of adding those two libraries:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.8
requests==2.22.0
soupsieve==1.9.5
urllib3==1.25.8
```

All of which are required for your project to import the modules correctly. Of course you will also need your boto3 and ask-sdk in your `requirements.txt`, however, they are natively included in lambda so therefore you do not need the dependencies.

For any libraries that aren't natively included in lambda you will need to follow this procedure. For a list of libraries that are natively included please see: [Lambda Packages](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/4a052f39490fae00e0c3#file-all_aws_lambda_modules_python3-7-txt).

Comment: I have skill builder set up and everything heres all of my code not just the handler chunk https://pastebin.com/YDLDaKpH

Comment: I see that you have configured that correctly :) I updated my answer to address the real issue

Comment: where do i go to use pipenv, lambada console? as of the moment im only coding in the alexa skills console. (thank you for all the help with this)

Comment: I don't think you would use this in the lambda console. I was thinking more on your local development machine. You dont necessarily need your Alexa project local, just a project you can generate the dependencies

Comment: my local dev machine has all of these installed in python but im developing the alexa skill on their website

Comment: You dont need to install them, you just have to have them in the requirements file. You install them locally to know all the dependencies that need to be in that file

Comment: after putting them in the requirements file i saved, deployed, and rebuilt my invocation model and still got the old "there was a problem with the requested skills response"

Comment: Can you go to the "code" tab and click on the "cloud watch logs" link as mentioned above to see what the error was?

Comment: i can look really quick

Comment: [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'ask_sdk_core'

Comment: With the code you pasted above these are the requirements.txt:
boto3==1.9.216
ask-sdk-core==1.11.0
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.8
requests==2.22.0
soupsieve==1.9.5
urllib3==1.25.8

Comment: i know i put them in and deployed it but still get no response